# Python variable names through a for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

In Matplotlib, I set an axis label using:
    axes1.set_ylabel('....')

If I have three axes, is there a way to use a loop to do the following?:

```
for i in range(3):
    axes[i].set_ylabel('AVG')
```

Of course, this is not correct syntax as I'm not using a list/dictionary. However, does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: well put your axes in a list and then just use your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your axes in a list:

```
my_axes = []
for n in range(1, 4):
    my_axes.append(fig.add_subplot(1, 3, n))
for ax in my_axes:
     ax.set_ylabel('AVG')
```

Comment: Now, how would you recommend I configure the subplots corresponding to each of the axes? For example                                                        axes1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 1)
axes2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 2)
axes3 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 3)

Comment: What do you mean by configure?

Comment: Just access them `ax[0]`?

Comment: So normally I do the following :axes1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 1)                          Is there anyway to use a for loop and generate a list of axes[n] = fig.add_subplot(...)

Comment: i really recommend `pyplot.subplots(nrows, ncols)` over writing a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use for multiple vertical-only axes:

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1, figsize=(12,5))
try:
    iter(axes)       # Check if axes can be iterated over
except TypeError:
    axes = [axes]    # If not, then make it into a list

for ax in axes:
    ax.plot(x, y)
    ax.set_ylabel('AVG')
```

Usually I even change the figure size depending on how many rows I have. Doing this gets a little complicated if you have `ncols > 1`. Therefore this is for vertical-only plots.